# Authorised routes are overwritten by buttons (React)

Tags: reactjs

I am making a basic website in which I have implemented a basic auth route. This gets the token and if the user has the token allows them to get to the pages they would like to be. This is shown below.

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component }) => (
  <Route
    render={props =>
      token && token !== undefined ? <Component /> : <Redirect to="/" />
    }
  />
);
```

This is then used in my app.js (Where all my react router routing is done).

```
 <AuthRoute
          exact
          path="/admin-center-view-users"
          component={AdminCenterViewUsers}
        />
```

So essentially its saying if they have the token(its a json web token I assigned them from my express back end ) allow them to gain access to this route. This works fine ,however I am using  for my buttons and this seems to completely ignore this route I have implemented.

This is how I have done my button routing. 
And this will take them to the page regardless of this route.

```
 <Link to="/RouteImNotAllowedToBe"> Sign Up </Link>
```

What would be a logical way to solve this issue? can similar things be done with a link tag?

EDIT

Express backend

```
app.post("/login", async (req, response) => {
  try {
    await sql.connect(config);

    var request = new sql.Request();
    var Email = req.body.email;
    var Password = req.body.password;
    var AccountValidationMessage = "";
    var LastLogin = req.body.date;

    let token = "";
    let adminToken = "";
    console.log({ Email, Password });

    request.input("Email", sql.VarChar, Email);

    let result = await request.execute("dbo.CheckEmailExists");

    if (result.recordsets[0].length > 0) {
      console.info("This email exists");
      request.input("Password", sql.VarChar, Password);
      let result = await request.execute("dbo.LoginUser");

      if (result.recordsets[0].length > 0) {
        console.info("/login: login successful..");
        console.log(req.body);

        request.input("LastLogin", sql.DateTime, LastLogin);

        await request.execute("dbo.AddLastLoginToRegisteredUsers");

        let result = await request.execute("dbo.FindAdmin");
        if (result.recordsets[0].length > 0) {
          console.info("This is a admin account");
          adminToken = jwt.sign({ user: Email }, "SECRET_KEY", {
            //////
            expiresIn: 3600000 ////////
          });
        } else {
          console.info("this aint a admin account but you get a login token"); //////
          token = jwt.sign({ user: Email }, "SECRET_KEY", {
            //////
            expiresIn: 3600000 ////////
          });
        }
        var decoded = jwt.verify(adminToken, "SECRET_KEY");
        console.log(decoded);

        response.status(200).json({
          ok: true,
          user: Email,
          jwt: token,
          adminJwt: adminToken
        });
      } else {
        console.info("Incorrect Password");
        AccountValidationMessage = "Incorrecrt password to account";
        response.status(409).json({
          AccountValidationMessage: AccountValidationMessage
        });
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Email does not exists");
      AccountValidationMessage = "Email does not exists";
      response.status(409).json({
        AccountValidationMessage: AccountValidationMessage
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Err: ", err);
    response.status(500).send("Check api console.log for the error");
  }
});
```

Example of jwt being assigned

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.email.length < 8 || this.state.password.length < 8) {
      alert(`please enter the form correctly `);
    } else {
      var today = new Date(),
        date = `${today.getUTCFullYear()}-${today.getUTCMonth() +
          1}-${today.getUTCDate()} ${today.getHours()}:${today.getMinutes()}:${today.getSeconds()}.${today.getMilliseconds()} `;

      const data = {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password,
        date
      };
      console.log(date);

      fetch("/login", {
        method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json,",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log("response before it is broken down " + response);

          return response.json();
        })
        .then(({ adminJwt, jwt, user, AccountValidationMessage }) => {
          console.log(
            "after it is broken down",
            jwt,
            adminJwt,
            user,
            AccountValidationMessage
          );
          window.localStorage.removeItem("registerToken");
          window.localStorage.removeItem("resetToken");
          if (jwt && user) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("myToken", jwt);
            window.localStorage.setItem("User", user);
          } else if (adminJwt && user) {
            window.localStorage.removeItem("myToken");

            window.localStorage.setItem("adminToken", adminJwt);
            window.localStorage.setItem("User", user);
          }
          if (AccountValidationMessage) {
            alert(AccountValidationMessage);
          }
        })

        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing down the path/exact props but they are not being used in your AuthRoute component, you can use the rest operator to fix this. You will also want to add props to the component in case future routes may need this.

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      token && token !== undefined ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
    }
  />
);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for trying to help but I added the rest operator in so that my code now matches yours but this did not solve the issue. If I go into my site and delete the token stored in local storage the buttons still work. The user is only kicked out once the page is refreshed but the user has full access to all pages as long as it is not refreshed.

Comment: Where is the token coming from? Are you using Redux for example? Can you post the full code which shows where the token is defined please?

Comment: Updated the question :)

Comment: Hi Henry, thanks for the update but is still not clear where the token is defined that is being used in your AuthRoute component where is 'token' initialized?

Comment: its set in the express back end then passed over to front end where it is saved to local storage.

Comment: I am not using redux

Comment: I can't see where you are getting the token from local storage.

Comment: that was just defined inside of the same file. So imagine just above my auth route I have "token =   window.localStorage.setItem("myToken", jwt);"

Comment: Hi Henry you need to use window.localStorage.getItem("myToken") to get the token value in storage.

Comment: If you add your code to a  [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) it will be easier for me to help